# How does Hive order numbers?

Tags: sql, string, hive, sql-order-by, hiveql

I noticed a weird Hive behaviour. It seems to not order columns right. this what I did:

```
select TAUX_REMU_RESEAU from t where id='000000010302'; // returns 7423.00

select TAUX_REMU_RESEAU from t order by TAUX_REMU_RESEAU desc; // and the first element was 9.60
```

How is this possible? Any explanation on how does Hive order its number columns please? Thank you.

Comment: Could you please send the TAUX_REMU_RESEAU column's data type? I assume its character. If yes, It is normal that the 9.60 is greater than 7423

Comment: You were right. The column was String. Thank you

Comment: We cannot see the simple one sometimes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which type column is.

If it is numeric type, their values compared:

```
with your_table as (
select stack(2, 7423.00, 9.60) as TAUX_REMU_RESEAU  
)

select * from your_table order by TAUX_REMU_RESEAU desc;
```

Result:

```
your_table.taux_remu_reseau
7423
9.6
```

If it is string:

```
with your_table as (
select stack(2, '7423.00', '9.60') as TAUX_REMU_RESEAU  
)

select * from your_table order by TAUX_REMU_RESEAU desc;
```

Result:

```
your_table.taux_remu_reseau
9.60
7423.00
```

Strings are compared lexicographically:

This is the definition of lexicographic ordering.

If two strings are different, then either they have different characters at some index that is a valid index for both strings, or their lengths are different, or both. If they have different characters at one or more index positions, let *k* be the smallest such index; then the string whose character at position *k* has the smaller value, as determined by using the < operator, lexicographically precedes the other string. In this case, `compareTo` returns the difference of the two character values at position `k` in the two string - that is, the value: `this.charAt(k)-anotherString.charAt(k)`

If there is no index position at which they differ, then the shorter string lexicographically precedes the longer string. In this case, `compareTo` returns the difference of the lengths of the strings - that is, the value: `this.length()-anotherString.length()`

See the [String.compareTo](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java) source code for better understanding:

```
public int compareTo(String anotherString) {

        int len1 = value.length;

        int len2 = anotherString.value.length;

        int lim = Math.min(len1, len2);

        char v1[] = value;

        char v2[] = anotherString.value;


        int k = 0;

        while (k < lim) {

            char c1 = v1[k];

            char c2 = v2[k];

            if (c1 != c2) {

                return c1 - c2;

            }

            k++;
        }

    return len1 - len2;
}
```

`compareTo` method returns after comparing characters at 0 position (k=0): 7 and 9.

Answer (score -1):

Presumably, the `id` is stored as a number of some sort -- an integer, decimal or whatever.

And `9.60` < `000000010302` as a number.

Comment: I think you misread the question. The first query proves that I have a TAUX_REMU_RESEAU = 7423.00 somewhere in my table. 

The second query which is supposed to order all TAUX_REMU_RESEAU in my table shows that the max one is equal to 9.60. 

Where did 7423.00 go?